# Better Line Detection Method in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I want to correct the perspective of my image with OpenCV using C++. I got help from [link1](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/) and [link](http://blog.ayoungprogrammer.com/2013/03/tutorial-creating-multiple-choice.html). Although I used the different techniques (cv::threshold, cv::adaptiveThreshold, cv::canny) on image and I tried to arrange the parameters of functions, I found more than 4 line. Edge of the my object doesn't have full straight line, so there are discontinities before hough transform. I added the some photos to give informations about my problem.

My original image:
[image]
After canny:
[image]
After adaptive threshold:
[image]
Detected lines  on image:
[image]
Any advice or sample would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You can straighten the edges by calibrating the camera (barrel correction, http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html ) that might give you better results, otherwise just pick one of the lines that are close to each other, or do an average of lines that are close together.

Comment: Averaging or picking one of lines make sense but how can I do them for 4 edge?

Comment: to correct perspective you only need 4 points (e.g. border corners) but you should correct distortion first! !!

Comment: Do you have suggestion for eliminating distortion? @Micka

Comment: use some easy to segment chessboard- or circlepattern and use calibrate3d opencv method to compute distortion coefficients. then use undistort method.